# How to add multiple labels using distinct using APOC for neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to add multiple labels to nodes using a cypher query, i would like to add 2 lables:

1. title
2. team

both exist on the node props:

```
CREATE (p:Person {id: 1, name: bob, title:developer, team: team1});
```

The following is working and adding the title as label:

```
match (n:Person)
with distinct n.title as title, collect(distinct n) as persons
call apoc.create.addLabels(persons, [apoc.text.upperCamelCase(title)]) yield node
return *
```

Instead of running the same query again with the team attribute, I would like to use the same one with multiple districts values something like:

```
with distinct n.title as title and with distinct n.team as team collect(distinct n) as persons
```

which is not working, any idea if this is possible? or should I run 2 different queries for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the requirement for the distinct values, as `apoc.create.addLabels` will ignore labels that already exist on the target node.

For example, given the following test data:

```
MERGE (: Person { id: 1, name: 'Both Properties', title: 'some title', team: 'some team' })
MERGE (: Person { id: 2, name: 'Only title', title: 'some title' })
MERGE (: Person { id: 3, name: 'Only team', team: 'some team' })
MERGE (: Person { id: 4, name: 'Neither team nor title' })
MERGE (: Person { id: 5, name: 'Same team and title', title: 'admin', team: 'admin' })
```

The following will build a list of labels to be created from the two properties, then set them:

```
MATCH (p: Person)
WITH p, [x in [p.title] + [p.team] WHERE x IS NOT NULL | apoc.text.upperCamelCase(x)] as desiredTitles
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(p, desiredTitles) YIELD node
RETURN p.name, labels(p)

╒════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════╕
│"p.name"                │"labels(p)"                      │
╞════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│"Both Properties"       │["Person","SomeTitle","SomeTeam"]│
├────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│"Only title"            │["Person","SomeTitle"]           │
├────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│"Only team"             │["Person","SomeTeam"]            │
├────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│"Neither team nor title"│["Person"]                       │
├────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│"Same team and title"   │["Person","Admin"]               │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

If either property is null then the list comprehension in the `WITH` statement will strip them out, and if they're the same then APOC ignores the duplicates automatically.